# Consume a rest service using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, rest

I want to to consume a rest service (http://xpto/twilioTeste-1.0-SNAPSHOT/webresources/tv/login?id=123ab2) this is a get and return xml. Is there any way to consume it without using jquery only using javascript. My objective is call it and store the xml in the file. I already tried

```
 var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhttp.open("GET", "http://xpto/twilioTeste-1.0-SNAPSHOT/webresources/tv/login?id=123ab2", false);
     xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/plain");
xhttp.send();
```

But the request is never sent.
Thanks for the help

Comment: Why are you setting a Content-type on a GET request?

Comment: please add one statement `xhttp.send();` below `xhttp.setRequestHeader` statement

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to send the request:

```
xhttp.send();
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to paste that line of code. But the code doesnt work work with it any way.

Comment: This code works for sure. Something else is the problem then. Did you check your developer tools for the request that is being fires? Also check for any javascript errors (that prohibit this code to run)